# Javascript: onkeydown in iframe?

Tags: javascript

I have a Site containing an Iframe containing some website for example google.com .
How can I apply onkeydown onto this iframe?
Seems to be kinda tricky...

Thx in advance!

Comment: I know nothing about it myself, but perhaps [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) can help you. It has [reasonably good support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging).

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, it is utterly impossible to directly interact with a different website using Javascript.

Comment: The script runs on my Site, it just stops to work when the iframe gets focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the child iframe, it is [possible](http://pipwerks.com/2008/11/30/iframes-and-cross-domain-security-part-2/) to have some level of communication, but if an iframe has focus, it is impossible to listen to it (or descend into) it so long as it is in a different domain.

Imagine, a malicious site decides that they want to do something similar. They open an iframe of your bank and then record your key-down events. That gives the malicious site access to your username and password! Bad deal.

Comment: Okay, is there a possibility to deactivate this in my browser or is this limited by javascript directly?

Comment: This is generally a browser security issue, but, with a browser extension, it is sometimes possible to circumvent it.